# align="right" doesn't work in XML

Tags: xml

I've never used XML before, and now I must change the align of text.
I try to do it like in HTML, but it doesn't happen.
Maybe I do something wrong?
Here is he script:

```
<gallery>
    <title><![CDATA[<FONT SIZE="20" COLOR="#C3A25D"></FONT>]]></title>
    <text><![CDATA[<FONT SIZE="20" COLOR="#C3A25D">text, which i want to to be in right position</FONT>]]></text>
    <thmb></thmb>
    <img wdt="421">images/avetiskhakhamyan.jpg</img>
</gallery>
```

I try to write `align="right"` in `<font>` tag, but it deosn't work.
Could you tell me what is the problem?

### Update:

And I can't understand anyway, if I don't set any `align` attribute, why it show text in center?
is it the default value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XML is not a display format. It doesn't not "understand" alignments.

As far as XML is concerned, `align="right"` is an attribute named `align` with the value `right`. Noting more and nothing less.

Comment: @Syom - XML is just a data format, not intended for viewing directly. The answer depends on _how_ you are viewing it and how you want it to be viewed by users of your application.

Comment: @Syom - You can use a CSS stylesheet for that. See this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_display.asp

Answer (score 2):

Plain XML? You need to apply a stylesheet to it, and that should be the part that identifies how to display the tag. Alignment is entirely part of display.

You can ask the browser (i.e., I've tested it with Safari and Firefox) to apply an XSLT stylesheet by adding a processing instruction to the XML document – usually immediately below the `<?xml…?>` declaration – which can do things like changing the document to XHTML (which *can* support alignment control):

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="http://example.com/wherever.xsl"?>
```

You might also be able to get away with just telling the browser what to do by applying a CSS stylesheet:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="http://example.com/wherever.css"?>
```

Ask further questions here if you need help learning how to use CSS, XSLT, or XHTML.

Comment: where i must apply the stylesheet? i've never work with xml, so could you write more clearly? thanks

Answer (score 2):

XML exists purely to describe and contain data. Presentation (colors, positioning, fonts etc.) is not part of what XML can or should be able to do.

You should take a look at [XLST](http://w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) (and therefore too HTML and CSS). That way you can format your data the way you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Paragraph>
    <TextRuns>
        <TextRun>
             <Value>=Parameters!rpReportSubHead1.Value</Value>
             <Style>
                 <FontWeight>Normal</FontWeight>
             </Style>
        </TextRun>
    </TextRuns>
    <Style>
        <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
    </Style>
</Paragraph>
```