# how to align the strings on the right edge?

Tags: android

I am trying to format string follows:

```
100;
  4;
104;
```

but I get so

```
100;
 4;
100;
```

here's part of my code that formats the strings

```
  String.format("\t%5s ", "100;" ),
  String.format("\t%5s ", "4;" ),
  String.format("\t%5s ", "104;" )
```

I output the these strings in the TextView (Android)

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPurchase"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvReturn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

could you please explain how can I format strings?

---

In the example of the link (http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) can be seen

[image]

how to do so?

```
Exam_Grade
         A
         B
         A
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this - http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html

For a general method we have:

```
public static String fixedLengthString(String string, int length) {
    return String.format("%1$"+length+ "s", string);
}
```

Maybe someone can suggest another format string to fill the empty spaces with an specific character?

Hope! It helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I did so under these rules, the problem is obtained if the strings is not the same length

Answer (score 0):

XML cannot format as well as CSS in that sense, its more for displaying UI objects. You want to apply a Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) document to be able to format it to the right.

**Reference to this - [align="right" doesn't work in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825893/align-right-doesnt-work-in-xml)**

**Check out style sheet syntax - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp**

Padding with blank chars isn't the best method unless this is intentional? (Its not that dynamic/good coding standards).

Or couldn't you just add padding in the XML document (left)?

Comment: The OP is asking about formatting strings in an Android UI, not in XML/HTML output.

Comment: You can apply style sheets in java android, and the android UI can use xml back end.

Comment: Its fairly standard, I've used style sheets for an entire application C++ with Qt. Either way XML surely can use padding to do so (as this is android UI)?

Answer (score 0):

Your general idea looks ok but without seeing your actual code, it's hard to say where it's going wrong.

Also, I'm not sure why you're trying to add a tab (`\t`) to the front of the each value.

Your code should look like:

```
TextView tvPurchaseTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPurchase);
tvPurchaseTextView.setText(String.format("%5s", "4;") );
```

You may also find some properties of TextView that will align your text neatly, rather than padding. Modifying your layout XML to the following for each TextView may help:

```
android:gravity="right"
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```